# load 2 folder static in django

Tags: javascript, python, django

in my project,I have 2 folder static. when I go into web game, django can load static js, css in folder game\static but it can't load img.
This is my directory structure:

[image]

go to web game, the chess not show pieces:
[image]

It load folder js and css but not load folder img

[image]

in file chessboard.js: `b.pieceTheme="static/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/{piece}.png"`

This is my static configuration in settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

I have a template that renders chess:

```
{% load static %}
<script src='{% static "js/chess.min.js" %}'></script>
<script src='{% static "js/chessboard-0.3.0.min.js" %}'></script>
<script src='{% static "js/main.js" %}'></script>
```

Comment: thats surprising. Because `main.js` is coming. maybe run `python manage.py collectstatic` and reload the application. I am assuming you are not using Django to serve the static contents.

Comment: @ruddra, I run `python manage.py collectstatic`, but it did not  run, terminal show `GET/game/static/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wB.png HTTP/1.1 400 72399 Bad Request: /game/static/img/chesspieces/wikipedia/wR.png`

Comment: I loaded img, fix this issue